# How do I pull data using SQLalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, discord.py

So I am using sqlalchemy as my orm in python, i am looking to see how to pull a certain bit of data.
This is the ORM model I built.

```
class ServerList(Base):
    # Table name
    __tablename__ = "ServerList"
    metadata_obj

    rID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    ServerID = Column(BigInteger)
    ServerName = Column(String(200))
    MemberCount = Column(Integer)
    ChannelCount = Column(Integer)
    Prefix = Column(String(200), default='H!')
    WelcomeEnabled = Column(BOOLEAN, default=False)
    LeaveEnabled = Column(BOOLEAN, default=False)
    AutoModEnabled = Column(BOOLEAN, default=True)
    MusicEnabled = Column(BOOLEAN, default=True)
    LastUpdate = Column(DATE)
```

Now I am trying to set it up so that each server this bot is in can have thier own prefix for it, how ever I need to pull that info from the data base, but can't seem to find a case that will work for me.

This piece of code is to fetch the prefix from the database but does not work as intended.

```
async def get_prefix(bot: commands.Bot, message: discord.Message):
    with Session(engine) as session:
        guild = session.query(ServerList).filter_by(ServerID=message.guild.id).first()
        if not guild:
            return PREFIX
        else:
            prefix = session.query(ServerList).filter_by(ServerID=message.guild.id).fetch(Prefix)
            return prefix
```

Any and all suggestions would be welcome. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this on my own, but I Figured I would post the solution I found.

so I first printed the query:

```
session.query(ServerList).filter_by(ServerID=ctx.guild.id).first()
```

which returned with a object

so by naming the query as a variable i can call var.Prefix

here is the code after the fix.

```
async def get_prefix(bot: commands.Bot, message: discord.Message):
    with Session(engine) as session:
        guild = session.query(ServerList).filter_by(ServerID=message.guild.id).first()
        if not guild:
            return PREFIX
        else:
            GuildData  = session.query(ServerList).filter_by(ServerID=message.guild.id).first()
            return GuildData.Prefix
```